# Calling redux action in useEffect before a different useEffect causes the second useEffect to be invoked twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
    data: [],
    loading: true
});
const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<UIAction>>();
useEffect(() => {
dispatch({
    type: SET_LOADING,
    loadbarShowing: true
})
}, [dispatch])
useEffect(() => {
const invoke = async () => {
    // Doing an effect here, including setting the state (including loading: false)
};
invoke();
}, [/* ... */]); // Even IF i pass an empty array here, it's still being invoked exactly twice.
```

The code above is somehow causes useEffect() to be invoked twice. If I don't call on `dispatch()` in the first useEffect, the second works perfectly.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: How the the parent render this component and Is the first useEEffect also invoking twice?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri The parent renders it normally. Only the second useEffect is being invoked twice.